# integration of Eclipse with symbian SDK

Tags: java, java-me

I want to develop a simple j2me application in eclipse and by using symbian s60 SDK but as i am completely new i dont know how to integrate eclipse and symbian sdk.

Answer (score 1):

First compile and run your app with J2ME emulator on eclipse. After that it will be easier to figure out Symbian SDK usage. Also Symbian forums probably have some tutorial on eclipse usage.

Answer (score 1):

Get the Eclipse Pulsar release from http://www.eclipse.org/pulsar/. It provides the integration with the S60 SDKs.